# Failed to find library: libmysqlclient.so.18

Tags: mysql, aws-lambda, zappa

I have flask API running on AWS lambda deployed using zappa.

While instancing it's not able to  find libmysqlclient.so.18 file which I believe consumes a lot of time.

Error message in attached image

Can someone please help?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: So weird, i'm also having this issue.

Comment: Please share all error messages in text form, along with your attempts to resolve them

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions proposed:

https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/issues/1834

1.

```
Django==2.0.0
Zappa==0.48.2
```

2. try to add the following to your zappa settings:

   "include": []